# spark elasticsearch read with basic auth giving 403 error

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch

I get this below error when I am trying to read from my ES cluster

```
org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.EsHadoopInvalidRequest: [DELETE] on [_search/scroll] failed; server[<HOST>:<PORT>] returned [403|Forbidden:]
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.checkResponse(RestClient.java:505)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.executeNotFoundAllowed(RestClient.java:476)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.deleteScroll(RestClient.java:541)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.ScrollQuery.close(ScrollQuery.java:77)
    at org.elasticsearch.spark.rdd.AbstractEsRDDIterator.close(AbstractEsRDDIterator.scala:81)
    at org.elasticsearch.spark.rdd.AbstractEsRDDIterator.closeIfNeeded(AbstractEsRDDIterator.scala:74)
    at org.elasticsearch.spark.rdd.AbstractEsRDDIterator$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractEsRDDIterator.scala:54)
    at org.elasticsearch.spark.rdd.AbstractEsRDDIterator$$anonfun$1.apply(AbstractEsRDDIterator.scala:54)
    at org.elasticsearch.spark.rdd.AbstractEsRDDIterator$$anonfun$1.apply(AbstractEsRDDIterator.scala:54)
```

Code used to read

```
// spark conf.
        SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf();
        sparkConf.setAppName("ReadORESData").setMaster("local[*]");

        // elasticsearch specific configuration.
        sparkConf.set("es.nodes", "<HOST>")
                .set("es.port", "<PORT>")
                .set("es.net.ssl", "true")
                .set("es.index.read.missing.as.empty", "true")
                .set("es.net.http.auth.user", "<USERNAME>")
                .set("es.net.http.auth.pass", "<PASSWORD>")
                .set("es.nodes.wan.only", "true")
                .set("es.nodes.discovery","false")
                .set("es.input.use.sliced.partitions","false")
                .set("es.resource", "<INDEX_NAME>")
                .set("es.scroll.size","500");

        JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);

        JavaPairRDD<String, Map<String, Object>> rdd = JavaEsSpark.esRDD(jsc);

        for ( Map<String, Object> item : rdd.values().collect()) {
            System.out.println(item);
        }

        jsc.stop();
```

curl is working fine from my machine.

`curl -XGET 'https://<HOST>:<PORT>/<INDEX>/_search' --user <USERNAME>:<PASSWORD>`

Any index I try I am seeing that same error. If invalid index it is correctly saying index not found. I am connecting to ES 5.6 cluster using these below dependencies.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch-spark-20_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.16</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Noticed that the account I was using doesn't have r/w permissions. Used a different account and it fixed that 403 error.